# AuthorizeAttribute Reuse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, code-reuse, authorize-attribute

I'm securing my MVC controllers with `AuthorizeAttributes`. Is there a way to instantiate those classes on its own?

At the moment I have an `AuthorizedAdmin` and a `IsAdmin` class which does the same. So ideally the `IsAdmin` should use the `AuthorizedAdmin` class. Is there a way to do that?

I'm asking because the `AuthorizedAdmin` is really simple:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizedAdmin : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizedAdmin()
    {
        Users = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADMIN_USERS"];
        Roles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADMIN_GROUPS"];
    }
}
```

on the other hand the `IsAdmin` class is more complex and duplicates functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can instantiate `AuthorizeAdmin` and call `OnAuthorization` on it.  It will be messy to work with the `AuthorizationContext` though.  Why not flip this around... put your business logic in `IsAdmin` and have `AuthorizedAdmin` use that?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's better not to force something. The reason I didn't want that was that the AuthorizedAdmin code is really simple. Didn't want to delete it :) or replace it with more complex code...

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need `IsAdmin`?  Why not just have a method called `GetAdminRole()` that returns the role string from your `AppSettings` and then use `User.IsInRole(GetAdminRole())`?

You can then use `GetAdminRole()` in your `AuthorizedAdminAttribute` as well.

Comment: The IsAdmin also has a user list to handle.. `users.Split(',').MatchUser...`. Hmm..but I think about your hint.. probably not bad even with user stuff.. thx